# Best way in inserting entry in database

Tags: java, mysql

I just like to know what is the best way in inserting values in a row in java, like what java programmer will do in inserting values, and tell me why?

Is it like this?

`String query = "insert into table (table1) values (1)";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.preparedStatement(query );
stmt.execute();`

or like this?

`String query = "insert into table (table1) values (?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.preparedStatement(query );
stmt.setInt(1,"1");
stmt.execute();`

Or is there a better way?

just asking to improve my coding knowledge :D

Comment: ALWAYS use the second option.  If you use the first option and build the statement from hard-coded strings and user input you will be open to SQL injection. The second method should be used whenever you have variable data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option allows variable input in your queries. If you can hard-code the values, then the first option is faster.

When you allow user input (where users can decide what values go into the query), then the second option allows you to put the values *safely* in the query. This, on the other hand, is a very big no-no:

```
String userInput = askUserForSomeValue();
String query = "insert into table (table1) values ("+userInput+")";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.preparedStatement(query );
stmt.execute();
```

Since it allows users to send [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) strings.

Comment: oh, so it depends on the situation, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Generally `Prepared` Statement is considered instead of a normal `Statement` due to it's pre-compilation and the DB-side caching of the statement which ideally leads to an overall faster execution and the ability to reuse the same SQL statement in batches. It's also pretty safe in preventing `SQL Injects` as well.

This [thread](https://coderanch.com/t/302422/databases/Statement-PreparedStatement) could be handy too.

Comment: I've read the thread, so statement is much slower when it comes in speed of compilation and preparedstatement is much faster because it doesn't need to be compiled, but in some cases statement is much efficient.

Answer (score 0):

PreparedStatements are the way to go, because they make SQL injection impossible.
Here's a simple example taking the user's input as the parameters:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO person (value) values (?)");
stmt.setInt(1,userinput);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: where con is connection object